# Which set does these Lego bricks belong to?

Tags: set-identification

There are 5 bags labeled N805. Pieces are black white and red and contain wheels. So I am thinking a vehicle of some kind???

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE. The numbers on the bag are not helpful for identification.  Can you upload pictures?